# Find the value of the integral: $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1}{3\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta}d\theta$

Tags: integration

> Using the substitution $t = \tan\theta$ , find the value of the integral:
>   $$\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \cfrac{1}{3\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta}d\theta$$

I isolated $\theta$ in $t = \tan\theta$, and then substituted the expression into the integral. I then replaced $d\theta$ by $dt$, which resulted in a very ugly, large expression.

The following is the answer given:

[image]

I do not understand how the first integral was obtained.

Comment: Through the identities $\cos^2\theta=\dfrac1{1+\tan^2\theta}$ and $\sin^2\theta=\tan^2\theta\cos^2\theta$

Comment: No wonder you didn't understand. The answer, though correct, is lacking proper information. For example, the differential is missing, which particularly in this substitution, is very important.

Comment: @imranfat, what do you mean?  I see the differential in the first step:  $dt = \sec^2\theta \, d\theta$.

Comment: Yes, I see it now .:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw a right triangle with an angle $\theta$.  Since $\tan\theta = t$, you can label the side opposite $\theta$ as $t$, and the side adjacent to $\theta$ as $1$.  Then the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{t^2+1}$.  Therefore:

$$ \cos\theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sin\theta = \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$

[image]

Can you take it from here?

Comment: If you write $\cos^2\theta = \dfrac 1 {t^2+1}$ then you avoid "$\pm$" issues. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, true, but in this case we were given $0 \le \theta \le \dfrac{\pi}{4}$ and I didn't want to explain more than we needed for this specific scenario.  I've been meaning to ask, why always (almost always) the $\verb|qquad|$ at the end of your comments?

Comment: @tilper : Do you see that without right-clicking on the blank space? (The blank space is its purpose and effect.) $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy- No, I see the blank space, but 12 years of $\TeX$ (plus the stack overflow app not rendering comments) tells me it's a qquad.  I know the what, just wondering about the why.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use that

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \cfrac{1}{3\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta}d\theta=\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}}{\frac{3\cos^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}+\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}d\theta=\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\sec^2\theta}{3+\tan^2\theta} d\theta=\int_0^1\frac{1}{3+t^2}dt$